# disable password policy using command prompt in Server 2008

Tags: command-line, passwords, windows-server-2008, group-policy

Is there a way to disable password policy in Windows Server 2008 using command prompt. I know how to do it using Local Security Policy in Administrative Tools. I was wondering if there is a way to change using command prompt. I guess there must be some registry settings that needs to be changed but I do not know which entry in registry will disable the password policy. If you can tell me which registry entry I can write the command prompt myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account policies cannot be changed directly through the Registry; they are handled by LSASS and stored along with user accounts. Microsoft provides [a complete list of Group Policy registry keys](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=18c90c80-8b0a-4906-a4f5-ff24cc2030fb&displaylang=en), and it says:

> Password Policy security settings are not registry keys.

There might be a way to change them through WMI or [Group Policy API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374177%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

---

On a stand-alone workstation, the "complexity requirements" bit is part of value `F` in key `HKLM\SECURITY\SAM\Domains\Account`.

**Don't even think about attacking LSASS with `regedit`.**